# After adding the Google Drive v2 APIs to android project, error Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpContent;

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've tried looking all over the place but I cannot figure out why this error is coming up after all I do is add the Google Drive API from the Google Plugin via Eclipse (Juno). When I clean the project the error doesn't appear. It is only when I go to run the Android application. I have been trying to follow the steps available at https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android
just to get the API and have also added the .jar/build path for Play Services.

This is the exact code that appears:

```
[2012-12-18 00:49:57 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpContent;
[2012-12-18 00:49:57 - Intro] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpContent;
```

I think this is related to duplicate dependencies to some level but I don't know which ones I should be keeping or deleting. Furthermore, I have already tried deleting the bin folder before adding the APIs and restarting, and it is not in the build path either. Below is a screen shot of the two libraries.

http://d.pr/i/tYvs

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have to jars that include the same classes (possibly different versions). Check the contents of the `libs/` folder and remove any duplicates. Or just start from scratch or a known working sample.

Comment: I just tried deleting all the duplicates and it still came up with this error. The app itself is already fully functional on other services and I am just trying to add a the Google Drive API library. Is there a better solution than pulling everything directly from the plug in?

Comment: The Google Drive plugin is likely not designed to work with Android. For Android (ADT), you need to have all jars under `libs/` and it will even point out the duplicates. Take a not of the jars and copy them under `libs/`.